# Rxjava - Can I invoke `Subject.onNext` method from different threads?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, rx-java

I have a Spring web server and I want to create a chat room for every N (for example 10) clients that requests my controller.

Every request to server has its own thread, how to collect every N request and create for example a room for it? I think that Rxjava has a solution for this so how can I implement this and if I can't do this, what's the best solution?

### Update 1:

With help of @pavan-kumar answer I created this:

```
@RestController
public class GameController {

    private final PublishSubject<Integer> subject;
    private AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Autowired
    public GameController(PublishSubject<Integer> subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {


        subject.buffer(10).subscribe(
                integers -> {
                    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("[ ");
                    for (Integer integer : integers) {
                        builder = builder.append(integer).append(", ");
                    }
                    String s = builder.append("]").toString();
                    System.out.println(s);
                });
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/game", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void findNewGame() {
        int i = counter.addAndGet(1);
        subject.onNext(i);

    }


}
```

So current question is "Can I invoke `Subject.onNext` method from different threads?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly. You have to provide serialization in some way or use the `toSerialized()` method and communicate with the returned `Subject<T, R>` instance.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> ps = PublishSubject.create();

Subject<Integer, Integer> subject = ps.toSerialized();

subject.subscribe(System.out::println);

subject.onNext(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Though the use case is not very clear for me, the below approach would probably help.

`Every request to server has its own thread` - Use a `static` `Observable` shared amongst all threads. May be you can call onNext every time a new user establishes a connection.

Once you have such `Observable`, you can subscribe to it via a `buffer` as depicted below.

```
Observable.range(1, 50).buffer(10).subscribe(n -> System.out.println(n.get(0)));
```

`Observable.range(1, 50)` is similar to your `static` `Observable` which emits events every time a connection is established. `buffer` takes care of merging all the items into a `List` of items and emits that one List when the said number of items(10) are emitted. You can `subscribe` on this and take appropriate actions as needed.